# Need to submit date from calender

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, jsp, form-submit

Here is my code.

```
   <div class="modal-content animate" >
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('Setpermissions').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <script>
            var nativePicker = document.querySelector('.nativeDateTimePicker');
            var fallbackPicker = document.querySelector('.fallbackDateTimePicker');
            var fallbackLabel = document.querySelector('.fallbackLabel');

            var yearSelect = document.querySelector('#year');
            var monthSelect = document.querySelector('#month');
            var daySelect = document.querySelector('#day');
            var hourSelect = document.querySelector('#hour');
            var minuteSelect = document.querySelector('#minute');

            // hide fallback initially
            fallbackPicker.style.display = 'none';
            fallbackLabel.style.display = 'none';

            // test whether a new datetime-local input falls back to a text input or not
            var test = document.createElement('input');

            try {
                test.type = 'datetime-local';
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.description);
            }

            // if it does, run the code inside the if() {} block
            if(test.type === 'text') {
                // hide the native picker and show the fallback
                nativePicker.style.display = 'none';
                fallbackPicker.style.display = 'block';
                fallbackLabel.style.display = 'block';

                // populate the days and years dynamically
                // (the months are always the same, therefore hardcoded)
                populateDays(monthSelect.value);
                populateYears();
                populateHours();
                populateMinutes();
            }

            function populateDays(month) {
                // delete the current set of <option> elements out of the
                // day <select>, ready for the next set to be injected
                while(daySelect.firstChild){
                    daySelect.removeChild(daySelect.firstChild);
                }

                // Create variable to hold new number of days to inject
                var dayNum;

                // 31 or 30 days?
                if(month === 'January' || month === 'March' || month === 'May' || month === 'July' || month === 'August' || month === 'October' || month === 'December') {
                    dayNum = 31;
                } else if(month === 'April' || month === 'June' || month === 'September' || month === 'November') {
                    dayNum = 30;
                } else {
                    // If month is February, calculate whether it is a leap year or not
                    var year = yearSelect.value;
                    var isLeap = new Date(year, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1;
                    isLeap ? dayNum = 29 : dayNum = 28;
                }

                // inject the right number of new <option> elements into the day <select>
                for(i = 1; i <= dayNum; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.textContent = i;
                    daySelect.appendChild(option);
                }

                // if previous day has already been set, set daySelect's value
                // to that day, to avoid the day jumping back to 1 when you
                // change the year
                if(previousDay) {
                    daySelect.value = previousDay;

                    // If the previous day was set to a high number, say 31, and then
                    // you chose a month with less total days in it (e.g. February),
                    // this part of the code ensures that the highest day available
                    // is selected, rather than showing a blank daySelect
                    if(daySelect.value === "") {
                        daySelect.value = previousDay - 1;
                    }

                    if(daySelect.value === "") {
                        daySelect.value = previousDay - 2;
                    }

                    if(daySelect.value === "") {
                        daySelect.value = previousDay - 3;
                    }
                }
            }

            function populateYears() {
                // get this year as a number
                var date = new Date();
                var year = date.getFullYear();

                // Make this year, and the 100 years before it available in the year <select>
                for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.textContent = year-i;
                    yearSelect.appendChild(option);
                }
            }

            function populateHours() {
                // populate the hours <select> with the 24 hours of the day
                for(var i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.textContent = (i < 10) ? ("0" + i) : i;
                    hourSelect.appendChild(option);
                }
            }

            function populateMinutes() {
                // populate the minutes <select> with the 60 hours of each minute
                for(var i = 0; i <= 59; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.textContent = (i < 10) ? ("0" + i) : i;
                    minuteSelect.appendChild(option);
                }
            }

            // when the month or year <select> values are changed, rerun populateDays()
            // in case the change affected the number of available days
            yearSelect.onchange = function() {
                populateDays(monthSelect.value);
            }

            monthSelect.onchange = function() {
                populateDays(monthSelect.value);
            }

            //preserve day selection
            var previousDay;

            // update what day has been set to previously
            // see end of populateDays() for usage
            daySelect.onchange = function() {
                previousDay = daySelect.value;
            }
        </script>




        <form id="toDate" action="Permissions"method="post">
            <div class="nativeDateTimePicker">
                <label for="party">Choose a date and time for your party:</label>
                <input type="datetime-local" id="party" name="toDate">
                <span class="validity"></span>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Class Permissions:

```
public class Permissions {
    private Time fromTime;
    private Date fromDate;
    private Time toTime;
    private Date toDate;
    private String reason;
    private String permission;

    public String getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }

    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public Date getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public Date getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }


    public Time getFromTime() {
        return fromTime;
    }

    public Time getToTime() {
        return toTime;
    }

    public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }

    public void setFromTime(Time from) {
        this.fromTime = from;
    }

    public void setToTime(Time to) {
        this.toTime = to;
    }



    public Permissions(){
        reason = null;
        permission = null;
        fromTime=Time.valueOf("00:00:00");
        toDate=Date.valueOf("2000-01-01");
        toTime=Time.valueOf("00:00:00");
        fromDate=Date.valueOf("2000-01-01");

    }


    public void setPermission(String permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }



    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }
}
```

This code displays a calender, from which a date can be selected.

I'm working on a spring mvc project, and I want to submit the date to the server. Changing form:submit is not working. So How can I do it?? Let the object be 'Permissions' (class components are given to you). Please help.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? What is not working? Is the submitted data errornous or isn't any data submitted or is the data not saved? And please post your controller code.

Comment: There is no option to submit. To enable the submit option I have to change input type to submit, and if I do that the calender wont work.

Comment: You must add submit button or something equivalent to your form. If you add the following to your form you can submit the calendar data to your controller. <button type="submit" name="submitMyFormButton">Submit</button>